# How to check if a token was approved?

Tags: uniswap, hardhat

I'm trying to use a simpple Uniswap V3 swap code from their documents with impersonateFunds.

```
//Here I should approve DAI

function swapExactInputSingle(uint amountIn)
        external
        returns (uint amountOut)
    {   //console.log(msg.sender);  Checking all possible errors in numbers
        //console.log(amountIn);
        //console.log(address(this));
        
        

        
        
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
            DAI,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            amountIn
        );

         TransferHelper.safeApprove(
            DAI, 
            address(swapRouter), 
            amountIn
        );
```

Looks like everything should work but I receive the error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'STF'
```

Community says that it's a problem with approvement (DAI in my case).
I tried several ways like this:

```
await dai.approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn)
```

where

```
dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI)
```

But I still get an error. Is there any way to know if DAI is approved or not?

Answer (score 0):

[DAI's smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F#code#L1) emits an Approval event and returns true if the transaction is approved.

```
function approve(address usr, uint wad) external returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][usr] = wad;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, usr, wad);
        return true;
    }
```

Therefore you can know whether the transaction was reverted or not by:

Option 1:

Checking whether is true or not.

```
if (await dai.approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn)){
    //insert your logic here
}
```

Option 2:

Storing the transaction receipt, reading it's events and defining your control flow.

```
const tx = await dai.approve(swapExamples.address, amountIn);
const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(receipt.events);
```

Option 3:

Listening to the on-chain event - [Ethereum DApps: How to Listen for Events](https://betterprogramming.pub/ethereum-dapps-how-to-listen-for-events-c4fa1a67cf81)

Comment: Thanks for several options. Looks like approve works so STF error is not about approving here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I didn't need to make the first transfer from Uniswap V3 example , because I already had DAI ready to spend.

```
// TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(
        //     DAI,
        //     msg.sender,
        //     address(this),
        //     amountIn
        // );
```

Answer (score 0):

in [DAI contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F#readContract) Check Approval from [allowence](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F#readContract#F3) read function.

In first  (address) put **Owner** address (your address)

In second  (address) put **Spender** address (Uniswap Address). Put address of spender, as address of contract which has `safeTransferFrom()` function